# jquery assign and call ID with variable

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

let's say i have this code below:

```
 textInput = $('#outputTextInput').val();

   $('#outputAdd').click(function(){

       $('#status_table tr:last').after('<tr id="output_newrow_"+textInput><td>1</td><td id="type_row_"+textInput>lala</td><td id="num_row_"+textInput>num row '+textInput+'</td><td><img class="image" src="static/OffLamp-icon.png" style="height:64px; width=64px"/></td></tr>');

    });
   $('#outputRemove').click(function(){

        $('#status_table').find("#output_newrow_"+textInput).remove();


   });
```

Then i would like to call that selector with ID "output_newrow_"+textInput or "type_row_"+textInput such that...

```
$('#how_should_i_write_it_here').append(textInput)
```

I have no idea how i should call that selector...

Thanks in advance for all the help :)

Update! Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/KGcrf/1/) link. My problem now is, i can't display the variable "textInput" and the index number is messy when i add and remove for a few times. For example, i key in "1,2,3" it will show index 2,3,4 on the table. but when i type in 3 and click remove, it removes index 2 (which is suppose to link to 1) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenations in your code are wrong, also in your code `index` is `undefined`.

```
$('#outputAdd').click(function(){
   var textInput = $('#outputTextInput').val();
   var str = '<tr id="output_newrow_' +textInput + '">'
               + '<td>1</td><td id="type_row_' + textInput '">lala</td>'
               + '<td id="num_row_' + textInput + '">num row ' + textInput + '</td>'
               + '<td><img class="image" src="static/OffLamp-icon.png" style="height:64px; width=64px"/></td>'
          +  '</tr>';
   $('#status_table tr:last').after(str);

});
$('#outputRemove').click(function(){
    $("#output_newrow_"+textInput).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks :D that makes sense to me now (sorry that i didnt update my codes above)! But '<td id="num_row_' + textInput + '">num row ' + textInput + '</td>' will only display "num row" in the table without showing what is the textInput.

Comment: @yvonnezoe You are welcome, please use `console.log(textInput)` and see what it returns, if it still doesn't work, please provide a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: hmm... console.log doesn't return anything to my terminal. FYI, this is part of a python code... does it matter? okay, i will try to transfer it to jsfiddle (never try it before :D )

Comment: here is the jsfiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/KGcrf/1/ :) thank you!

Comment: @yvonnezoe That's because you're storing the value on the page load, when it's empty, I have updated your fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/U8Kn9/

Comment: Thank you! :D ohh so the remove button is now at the side (the red cross) right? that's a brilliant idea! thanks! :) but is it still possible to key in the number and use the "remove" button?

Comment: @yvonnezoe You are welcome, do you see the `x` cell? it removes the row.

Comment: haha yes i just saw and edited my reply :)

Comment: @yvonnezoe Yes it is possible, but you should create a remove button for each row, I think it is not user-friendly.

Comment: i see, that's very tedious. Thank you for your help and advices :)

Comment: opps. i've got a problem on my real program... i removed the first default row and the index shows "4" all the way. I added that row back, and i get 14,15,16 etc after removing one row. i have other tables in the program. not sure if they affect the current table?

Comment: @yvonnezoe Yes it affects the current table, use `#status_table` in the selectors explicitly , it should solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but may be you can take a look at the continuation of my problem here? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162040/jquery-how-to-clear-replace-the-stored-value-in-a-variable-got-from-val

Answer (score 0):

Your string concatenation was wrong

```
$('#outputAdd').click(function(){
    var textInput = $('#outputTextInput').val();

    $('#status_table tr:last').after('<tr id="output_newrow_'+textInput+'"><td>1</td><td id="type_row_"+textInput>lala</td><td id="num_row_"+textInput>num row '+index+'</td><td><img class="image" src="static/OffLamp-icon.png" style="height:64px; width=64px"/></td></tr>');

});
$('#outputRemove').click(function(){
    $('#status_table').find("#output_newrow_"+textInput).remove();    
});
```

Comment: you meant this? id="output_newrow_'+textInput+'" but i tried that too. it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same way you are assigning it. Like this:

```
$("#output_newrow_" + textInput).appen(textInput);
```

Comment: no it doesn't work :( textInput = $('#outputTextInput').val();

       $('#outputAdd').click(function(){
           
           $('#status_table tr:last').after('<tr id="output_newrow_"+textInput><td>1</td><td id="type_row_"+textInput>lala</td><td id="num_row_"+textInput></td><td><img class="image" src="static/OffLamp-icon.png" style="height:64px; width=64px"/></td></tr>');
           $('#num_row_'+ textInput).append(textInput);
        });
       $('#outputRemove').click(function(){