# jQuery How to clear / replace the stored value in a variable (got from .val() )

Tags: jquery, variables, text, input

Thanks to all the help previously, i have managed to come to this far: I am able to add row to the table and select an option and display a text input. 
Here is the [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/5cbjt/1/). Previously i used multiselect but i changed to single select now because multiselect has caused problem in display my "Output Type" (may be you can suggest better ways to do it ;) )

Now I am facing another problem where the value stored in the variable will not get replaced by the new input value. Therefore, "Output Number" column will only show the first number input. Another weird thing is, it can only take in/update input from 'Zone Input' as it is placed the first in the html div. i tried to change others to the top and same thing happened too.

```
var textInput = "";
$('.TextInput').empty();
textInput = $('.TextInput').val();
```

I tried `.empty()` but it doesn't work as you can see. Each of the div has different ID. But if i use ID like i tested for just one of them previously, `var textInput = $('#outputTextInput').val();` , how can i do it the same for others? do i use OR `||` like
`var textInput = $('#outputTextInput').val() || $('#zoneTextInput').val();` ?

Also, must i create another function for "Arm" since it is using a checkbox rather than text input?

Update: This is working but not on my program :(( http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/MKfLU/1/

**UPDATE: I found the problem with this!** See my problem here: [jQuery vs jQuery Mobile - Does the script sequence matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181610/jquery-vs-jquery-mobile-does-the-script-sequence-matter)

Comment: $('.TextInput') grabs everything with class="TextInput". Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: :O oh yaa, but no that's not what i want. i thought it would be tedious to use the ID...and i'm not too sure how to replace that .TextInput with respective IDs

Comment: It's generally a good idea to start with an ID. Then you use css selector rules to select your desired element. So you would do something like $('#sensorText input.TextInput')

Comment: so you mean i should use the OR statement? but it's still the same... http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/6bEDH/ only the first one (sensorTextInput in this case) can update the value...

Comment: textInput=$(this).prev().val(); is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this lines in your code:

```
$('.TextInput').empty();
textInput =  $('.TextInput').val();
```

With this:

```
$('.TextInput').not($(this).prev('.TextInput')).val('');
textInput =  $(this).prev('.TextInput').val();
```

and try again...

Here's your markup:

```
<input type="text" class="TextInput" id="zoneTextInput" value="">
<input type="submit" class="add" value="Add" />
```

Now when you click on the Add button with class `add`, then `$(this)` represents the element in the current scope and the `$(this).prev('.TextInput')` represents the element previous to it with the class `TextInput` (Here, the input text-box). So, `$(this).prev('.TextInput').val()` will give you the value of the current textbox with add button you have clicked. Whereas, `$('.TextInput').val()` gives you the value of the first element no matter which add button is clicked.

For more details: [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: thank you! it works on fiddle but it doesn't work on my program :( now it cant add anything. any idea why?

Comment: I am quite not sure what is happening wrong at your end. Might be the markup in the Fiddle and in your program are different? Can't say anything w/o looking at your code :(

Comment: :( hmm that is so weird but anyway do you mind to explain your codes? :) i don't quite get the $(this).prev

Comment: thanks for the explanation. that makes sense! :D but it's weird that it doesnt work in my real program :((

Comment: Not sure what's happening in your program.. :(

Comment: :( thanks anyway :)  should i copy everything in my program to the fiddle? :O

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working for me. Also the alert `alert(textInput);` is coming correct! What is the specific issue you are having???

Comment: on my webpage, it gave "undefined" though :( and i've just match all the js script. and it's still the same..

Answer (score 0):

textInput=$(this).prev().val(); works because in the click event, this is pointing to the button, prev selects the prior element in the dom (in this case the input element) and then .val() selects the value of it. What part still isn't working?

Comment: yes it works fine in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/MKfLU/3/ but not in my whole program here: http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/MKfLU/2/

Comment: any idea why it gave "undefined" on my web app but not on fiddle?

Comment: it is undefined on Fiddle as well now :/ jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/7NZzr

Comment: You need to understand what $(this).prev().val(); is supposed to do. Your prev() is no longer the input. The point is to navigate the dom from $(this) which is the add button. In your most recent example prev() points at a span. So that no longer works, but jquery provides functions that allow you to get to the input from the add button so that you can get the value.